# Write out page title <title>THIS</title> in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, title

I have this:

```
<head>
<title>This is my title</title>
</head>
```

How do I then in  make a .ASP script that writes out the content of the title ^^

Comment: Have you ever done ASP before? Output of a fixed string is an utter core operation in pretty much any web-based language.

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse HTML for the `<title>` element's content. Zalgo won't be pleased.

Comment: Im sorry but i don't know how to do it - can you tell me? - so me and other users can see how to do it? :)

Comment: Start with looking for asp and "Hello World" on Google You should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: I'm with some other folks on this - but you haven't posted anything you've tried.  It seems you're expecting others to write a solution for you, and unfortunately, that's not how it really works here.  If you'd like more assistance, you should post what you have tried.  Then folks are able to guide you more efficiently, else they'll be pointing in all sorts of directions.  

In this case, the above comments really sum up the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
<title><%="This is my title"%></title>
```

or

```
<title><%=String%></title>
```